# Strange code in auto-complete textbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to understand this code https://gist.github.com/asainz/8d0e98970085ba6e76d2

```js
 link: function(scope, element, attrs){

      setTimeout(function() {
        scope.initLock = false;
        scope.$apply();
      }, 250);

      var attr = '';

      // Default atts
      scope.attrs = {
        "placeholder": "start typing...",
        "class": "",
        "id": "",
        "inputclass": "",
        "inputid": ""
      };

      for (var a in attrs) {
        attr = a.replace('attr', '').toLowerCase();
        // add attribute overriding defaults
        // and preventing duplication
        if (a.indexOf('attr') === 0) {
          scope.attrs[attr] = attrs[a];
        }
      }
```

It doesn't seem to do anything and I think the author's idea was to use attributes defined in the page if defined and if not use default scope.attrs.

I think we should loop through properties of scope.attrs, check if we have them in attrs and replace. If I am right, how should I change the code above to match the original intent of that code?

Comment: this code definitely does something.... the original code this is derived from shows they use `attr-placeholder`, `attr-class`, etc...  https://github.com/JustGoscha/allmighty-autocomplete

Comment: I see. I was wondering why I added id and inputid and nothing happened. They should have been attr-id, etc. Still the above seems to be a bit inefficient judging by how many attributes we need to loop to only set a few we need. Wouldn't it somehow better to loop through  scope.attrs properties instead? I was trying to figure out how to loop through properties of the object.

Comment: I tried to re-write the opposite way, but was unable, so I just made sure to use correct way in HTML. It does indeed work for attr- attributes